# Angular editar os valores de um objeto sem alterar o "original"

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um `ng-repeat` em `Angular` cujo valor de cada iteração é um objeto. Ao clicar num botão referente a linha da tabela onde esse objeto é utilizado, um formulário para edição do mesmo é aberto, e, com esses dados, preencho esse formulário.

Assim:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Test', function ($scope) {

  $scope.users = [
    {name: 'Wallace', email: 'wallacemaxters@gmail.com'},
    {name: 'Wayne', email: 'wayne.souza@gmail.com'}
  ];
  $scope.edit = function (user) {

    $scope.user = user;
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="Test" class="container"> 
        <table class='table'>
            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                <td>Name: {{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>E-mail: {{ user.email }}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(user)">editar</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <form ng-if="user">
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control" />
            <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" class="form-control" />
           <button type="submit" ng-click="save()" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
            
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Porém eu gostaria que o valor do objeto selecionado, ao ser editado no formulário, não atualizasse imediatamente os valores da tabela, mas apenas ao clicar no botão "salvar".

Como eu posso "quebrar" essa referência temporariamente no Angular e, depois, atualizá-la novamente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

Uso o [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) dentro da função `edit` que retorna apenas uma cópia do objeto, e um segundo argumento nesta que seria o `index` do array users que correspondente ao objeto modificado. Uso este index posteriormente para atualizar somente a parte que foi modificada:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('Test', function($scope) {
    var index;
    $scope.users = [{
      name: 'Wallace',
      email: 'wallacemaxters@gmail.com'
    }, {
      name: 'Wayne',
      email: 'wayne.souza@gmail.com'
    }];
    $scope.edit = function(user, i) {
      $scope.update = angular.copy(user);
      index = i;
    }
    $scope.save = function() {
      $scope.users[index] = $scope.update; // captura o objeto modificado e atualiza no original
      $scope.update = ""; // reseta o update
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Test" class="container">
  <table class='table'>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>Name: {{ user.name }}</td>
      <td>E-mail: {{ user.email }}</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="edit(user, $index)">editar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <form ng-if="update">
    <input type="text" ng-model="update.name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="email" ng-model="update.email" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" ng-click="save()" ng-submit="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo. +1

Answer (score 1):

Na sua função `edit` crie um novo `object` copiando o user com a função `create`, como segue:

```
var user_orginal = { a : 1 };
var user_clone = Object.create(foo);
user_orginal.a; // 1
user_clone.a; // 1
user_orginal.a = 2;
user_clone.a; // 2 - prototype changed
user_clone.a = 3;
user_orginal.a; // Still 2, since setting bar.a makes it an "own" property
```

Depois, na função save, atribua o user_clone para o `$scope.user`.

---

Fonte: [SO - en - How do I correctly clone a javascript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)